# Proper use of pauses: semicolons or commas

Tags: commas, semicolons, comma-splices

Am I using the proper phrasing in the following sentence?

> In times like these, the first thing we run out of is time; and since
>   none of us can create more of it, the only solution we have is to
>   optimize our use of it.

Comment: Period!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Well done - the semicolon fits. I limit myself to one per page, since some readers are not sure what to make of it.

Comment: If you use the semicolon then you don't need the "and'; the semicolon is equivalent to 'and' in this context.

Comment: True, but the _and_ is useful. And not everything has to be as short as possible.

Comment: Incidentally, the comma is not a "pause"; if you actually analyze normal speech, there are no pauses. Except occasionally at sentence boundaries. The difference between a semicolon and a full stop is inaudible in speech. In writing the difference is stylistic, representing possible intonation contours. But commas don't ever pause; they just change the intonation, like this.

Comment: No for the semicolon. Replace it with a period and capitalize *And*...

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat: What about just replacing semicolon with a comma, and leaving the remaining as it is?

Comment: @RamPillai: Yes, that is correct too. But that's a lot of commas.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have several questions regarding your second comment. Can you clarify these? ... 1) Re your first sentence ("comma is not a 'pause'; if you actually analyze normal speech, there are no pauses") -- but we are talking about writing and so how people read, and people do read differently. Are you saying the fact that it's true in speech means that it's as true in writing too? If so, why? ... 2) "The difference between a semicolon and a full stop is inaudible in speech" What do you mean by this? I believe that the intonation for the semicolon actually *very rarely* occurs . . .

Comment: [contd.] in speech and that where we would use a semicolon in writing, we instead most frequently use the intonation for the comma (comma splices abound in speech), and *then* that of the period. With what points here do you disagree with me? ... 3) What did you mean by the difference between a semicolon and a full stop being "stylistic" in writing?

Comment: There is no single way in which "people read". Reading is a technological task for which humans have no evolutionary adaptation, so it's not like walking or talking. That means that every reader figures it out for themself. Regardless of what they're taught or not taught. (2) Full stop intonation is a falling tone. It can't be distinguished aurally from the falling tone represented by a semicolon. There is no "intonation for the semicolon" -- the intonation comes first, and centuries later the punctuation represents it..

Comment: As for the stylistic nature of the distinction in writing, see [what Lewis Thomas had to say about it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html).

Comment: @HotLicks: Why? Do you think the use of a semicolon or comma there is incorrect? How?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed - Nothing in English is incorrect.  It's just that some things are correcter than others.

Comment: @HotLicks: I think that's trivially false. If your first sentence was "Nothing in English of have incorrect", that would be unambiguously incorrect, for example. Regarding my original question, I still don't understand why you see using a full stop more correct there than a comma or even a semicolon. Can you explain?

Comment: @Tinfoil: Can you explain why you don't think a semicolon should be used in the given sentence? Other people above, like Yosef Baskin, don't seem to have any problem with it.

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed: *Rule: Use a semicolon between closely related independent clauses which are not joined by a coordinating conjunction.* The OP's sentence has both a semicolon and a conjunction (*and*). Remove *and* or change the semicolon to a comma or a period. https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/punctuation/using-semicolons/